# React Google Maps marker position is misplaced with usage of OverlayView

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, components, react-google-maps

I am using react-google-maps and showing some markers on the map..the issue is that the actual latitude longitude where the marker should be looks far away from where it should be…only when you completely zoom in the marker is placed correctly(almost as here too there is little difference).Attached two snapshots.
I am using following code

```
<OverlayView
    position={{ lat: annotation.props.lat, lng: annotation.props.lng }}
    mapPaneName={OverlayView.FLOAT_PANE}
 >
 {annotation}
 </OverlayView>
```

Image 1.Marker A and the nearest orange colored marker and not two different markers..they are the same lat long..still at this zoom level looks far away[image]

Image 2:after complete zoom in

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question,this was resolved after replacing OverlayView with Marker